# How to set Environment Variable For ExoPlayer FFmpeg extension?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-ffmpeg

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ffmpeg Here they show how to set Environment variable for ffmpeg extension. But when i type these command in android studio terminal.

```
cd "<path to exoplayer checkout>"
EXOPLAYER_ROOT="$(pwd)"
FFMPEG_EXT_PATH="${EXOPLAYER_ROOT}/extensions/ffmpeg/src/main"
```

Following error is generated.

```
'EXOPLAYER_ROOT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'FFMPEG_EXT_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also set it in Environment Variable but when i type command in terminal same error are generated. I want to know the proper way to set enviroment variable for ffmpeg extension. It's almost 2nd day i'm trying to solve it but no succeed. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set environment variables in ~/.bashrc file in linux as following. In your terminal type:

gedit ~/.bashrc

at the end of this file add the following:
export FFMPEG_EXT_PATH="your ffmpeg directory"

Save and exit. Reset your terminal. Then type:

echo $FFMPEG_EXT_PATH